# Apache Karaf - CXF REST server address

Tags: java, rest, osgi, cxf, apache-karaf

I am developing a RESTful web service in Apache Karaf, using CXF-JAXRS. This is the code I am running:

```
JAXRSServerFactoryBean bean = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();

bean.setBus(BusFactory.getDefaultBus(true));
bean.setAddress("/" + MY_ADDRESS);
bean.setProvider(new JacksonJsonProvider());
bean.setServiceBean(myService);

Server server = bean.create();
```

By now I managed to create the server and access some methods, but its address is http://localhost:8181/cxf/MY_ADDRESS/. How can I remove the "/cxf" prefix, and run the server on http://localhost:8181/MY_ADDRESS/? Also, is it possible to run the server on a different port?

If I try to run  `bean.setAddress("http://localhost:8181/" + MY_ADDRESS);` instead, I get "404 Not Found"  when trying to access it.

Answer (score 0):

if this is still issue, you can check for blueprint xml where you can remove this 'cxf' from your REST URL and to run on different port you need to update the config xml